# How to match all email addresses at a specific domain using regex?

Tags: regex

I need help on finding a regex expression that will match email addresses  of only a specific domain

As in any `.*@testdomain.com`

And also the opposite any thing other than `.*@testdomain.com`

Comment: Which regex engine (programming language) are you using? Why use a regex at all? `subject.endswith("@testdomain.com")` appears to be enough (Python example).

Comment: You want to find every email @testdomain.com **AND** the opposite, "any other thing". Does that mean you want to find everything ??? If so, then just use your string, other wise you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @Stema, i think the sasuke problem is a theoric speculation, check my regex proposal to have maybe some clarifications

Comment: I am using a program that will take the expression as input, the program uses regex++ library

Answer (score 51):

I propose an expression very simple:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@testdomain\.com$
```

The `.` in the domain must be escaped as well.

and for the negative check:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@(?!testdomain.com)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$
```

Comment: That will match the text `@testdomain.com` and it isn't a valid email.

Comment: Matching a specific domain like "@testdomain.com" it was the first specification of sasuke, and a regex to match a valid email address is already disponible on the net. i wanted to focus the attention of sasuke on the part relative to the domain

Comment: @Marcello I don't see where the OP said that it should match `@testdomain.com`. All I see is `.*@testdomain.com` and I'm almost sure he used it as a wildcard (like when searching in Windows Explorer or similar). Otherwise, he shouldn't be askin that question.

Comment: Ok for the wildcard (it was for simplification purposes, and i correct that as you wish) but sasuke want 2 thing: "a regex expression that will match email addresses of only a specific domain" and the oppsite "any thing other than .*@testdomain.com"

Comment: What are you telling me with that? What is `any thing other than .*@testdomain.com`? Is he refering to emails? or any strings? It isn't clear at all. **any thing other than it** could be `1`,  or `$$$`,...

Comment: Oscar, the answer is already there "the opposite any thing other than .*@testdomain.com" it means: ^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?!testdomain.com)[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$ . are you ok about that now? Then you can vote for me ;-) PS: And yes he is refering to emails

Comment: +1 because you gave a good answer to a not so clear question.

Comment: Thanks Stema, anyway Oscar also has been helpful in order to elaborate a satisfying answer

Comment: The `.` in testdomain.com needs to be escaped, otherwise `something@testdomainxcom` would pass too.

Comment: what if i want to restrict more than one specific domains?

Answer (score 1):

For my particular scenario, I needed this variation:

```
'^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@' + email_domain + '$'
```

this would match an email_domain from a list of email_domains: ['example1.com', 'example2.co.uk'] and I was running through the list, matching each one against a list of email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

@Kushal I found an easy way to do this, but it was somewhat tricky, because I had to retrieve via ajax the domain from a global variable stored somewhere else.

Here is the following line of code inside a javascript validation method:

```
return new RegExp("^\\w+([-+.']\w+)*@"+getDomain.responseJSON.d+"$").test(value.trim());
```

I create a new RegExp on the spot and test the value (email input) to see if it matches the domain.

- The string inside quotes is the regex that may contain any kind of name the user has.
- The getDomain.responseJSON.d,  is the dynamic global domain variable (in case I want it changed and did not want to interfere with the source code.) that was retrieved with a $.getJSON(); call to a WCF service.

If you want something more elaborate but have standard domains, then it can go like this:

```
return /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@?(example1.com|example2.com)$/.test(value.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oE '( |^)[^ ]*@testdomain\.com( |$)' file.txt
```

-o Returns only the matched string

The above will give all email id's of testdomain in file.txt.

Comment: This is not correct. It will match invalid emails, `@testdomain.com`, or `name,lastname@testdomain.com`.

Answer (score -2):

You can also set as below regex.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@testdomain\.com$/gm
```

Comment: This would also match "abc@gmail.com", or "abc@gmail". But it wouldn't match "abc@hotmail.com"

Comment: This will match `abc@gmail#com` but not match `abc.123-456+789@GMAIL.COM` (for several reasons). Also, the edit didn't stop it from matching "abc@gmail.com".