# Match all email addresses belonging to a specific domain and its subdomains

Tags: ruby, regex, email, string-matching

I am looking to match all email addresses from a specific domain.

Any email coming from `example.com` or `foo.example.com` should match, everything else should be rejected. To do this, I could do some basic string matching to check if the given string ends with, or contains, `example.com` which would work fine but it also means that something like `fooexample.com` will pass.

Hence, based on the above requirements, I started working on a pattern that would pass the domain and its sub-domain. I was able to come up with the following regex pattern:

```
`/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.example.com\b/i`
```

This only matched subdomains, but I have seen the pattern at "[How to match all email addresses at a specific domain using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191560/how-to-match-all-email-addresses-at-a-specific-domain-using-regex)" which handles the main domain.

Is there a way to combine these two into something that works for [any address from example.com](http://rubular.com/r/elQJF06igX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
/\b(?:(?![_.-])(?!.*[_.-]{2})[a-z0-9_.-]+(?<![_.-]))@(?:(?!-)(?!.*--)[a-z0-9-]+(?<!-)\.)*example\.com\b/i
```

Answer (score 0):

This one would also match 'tagged' and 'tagged-subdomain' mails like a+b@example.com and a+b@i.example.com

```
(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@(?:(?!-)(?!.*--)[a-z0-9-]+(?<!-)\.)*example\.com\b
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading "[Stop Validating Email Addresses With Your Complex Regex](http://davidcelis.com/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email)".

From that point, I'd look for:

```
/@.*\bexample\.com/
```

For instance:

```
%w[foo@example.com foo@barexample.com foo@subdomain.example.com].grep(/@.*\bexample\.com/)
=> ["foo@example.com", "foo@subdomain.example.com"]
```

It's too easy to end up with a regex that is a maintenance nightmare, and that doesn't accomplish what you need. I highly recommend keeping it simple.